# Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to setup some controllers in my angular app but I'm not sure why I can't make them working, since I think I'm using similar approach as I've done before.

I declared app.js file:

```
'use strict';

var modules = [
    'app.controllers',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.router',
    'LocalStorageModule',
    'angular-loading-bar'
];

var app = angular.module('app', modules);

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
})

app.factory('forgotPasswordService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var fac = {};

    fac.forgotPassword = function (forgotPasswordData) {
        return $http.post('/api/Account/ForgotPassword', forgotPasswordData)
    };

    return fac;

}])

app.factory('signUpService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var signUpServiceFactory = {};

    signUpServiceFactory.saveRegistration = function (registration) {
        return $http.post('/api/account/register', registration);
    };

    return signUpServiceFactory;
}]);
```

Then controllers.js file with this content:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
    .controller('signupController', [
        '$scope', '$window', 'signUpService',
        function($scope, $window, signUpService) {
            $scope.init = function() {
                $scope.isProcessing = false;
                $scope.RegisterBtnText = "Register";
            };

            $scope.init();
            $scope.IsLimitedCompany = null;
            $scope.registration = {
                Email: "",
                Password: "",
                ConfirmPassword: ""
            };

            $scope.signUp = function() {
                $scope.isProcessing = true;
                $scope.RegisterBtnText = "Please wait...";
                signUpService.saveRegistration($scope.registration).then(function(response) {
                    alert("Registration Successfully Completed. Please sign in to Continue.");
                    $window.location.href = "login.html";
                }, function() {
                    alert("Error occured. Please try again.");
                    $scope.isProcessing = false;
                    $scope.RegisterBtnText = "Register";
                });
            };
        }
    ]);
```

And my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <script src="/Metronic/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Angular/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/Angular/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Angular/Services/authInterceptorService.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="login">
    <div class="content" ng-app="app">
        <!-- BEGIN REGISTRATION FORM -->
        <div class="register-form" ng-controller="signupController">
            <h3 class="font-green">Sign Up</h3>
            <p class="hint"> Enter your account details below: </p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" ng-model="registration.Email" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" name="username" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" ng-model="registration.Password" type="password" autocomplete="off" id="register_password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Re-type Your Password</label>
                <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" ng-model="registration.ConfirmPassword" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Re-type Your Password" name="rpassword" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Role</label>
                <select name="role" ng-change="CheckRole()" ng-model="registration.Role" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Role</option>
                    <option value="Borrower">Borrower</option>
                    <option value="Introducer">Introducer</option>
                    <option value="Investor">Investor</option>
                    <option value="Valuer">Valuer</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="button" id="register-back-btn" class="btn green btn-outline">Back</button>
                <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-success uppercase pull-right" ng-click="signUp()" ng-disabled="isProcessing" value="{{RegisterBtnText}}">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END REGISTRATION FORM -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what am I missing?

I'm getting this error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'signupController' is not a function, got undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included JS file in wrong order.

Currently it is

```
<script src="/Angular/app.js"></script>
<script src="/Angular/controllers.js"></script>
```

Because of this your app.js not getting the defination of app.controllers.

Its should be like this one

```
<script src="/Angular/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="/Angular/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Rijay-khan thanks for your reply but I'm getting the same error when I'm switching the places. When I'm pushing app.js all the way at the bottom of the list I'm getting this error: https://i.gyazo.com/c717bd341e7f7b7fd473190475214bc8.png Thanks for helping me out

Comment: In which file it is defined authServiceInterceptorProvider?

Comment: Is it defined as factory or service?

Comment: Thanks, that interceptor was using different app declaration. I set that to my app and works perfectly now. Have a good weekend!